# Responsive navbar to layout space

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I want to set design responsive when `layout` is smaller than `nav`

[image]

As you can see its layout is small and nav does not adjust to layout content, I try using `width: max-content;` on `nav` but it does not cause any effect.

How can I achieve that? Regards

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/geringanetor/pen/MWoOxbV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need this

```
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: have a nice day